# On Piecewise Function

Tags: plotting, graphics, calculus-and-analysis

Defined:

```
f[x_] = Piecewise[{{(x - 2)^2 - 1, 1 < x < 3}, 
                   {0, True}}];

x1 = 0.24;
```

writing:

```
fT[x_] = Piecewise[{{f[2], 2 - x1 <= x <= 2 + x1}, 
                    {f[x + x1], f'[x] <= 0}, 
                    {f[x - x1], f'[x] >= 0}}];

plot1 = Plot[{f[x], fT[x]}, {x, 0, 4}]
```

I get:

[image]

while writing:

```
fT[x_] = Piecewise[{{f[2], 2 - x1 <= x <= 2 + x1}, 
                    {f[x - x1], f'[x] >= 0}, 
                    {f[x + x1], f'[x] <= 0}}];

plot2 = Plot[{f[x], fT[x]}, {x, 0, 4}]
```

I get:

[image]

In light of this, it is clear that:

```
Show[plot1, plot2]
```

[image]

but unfortunately I just can not find a way to define a piecewise function (in an automated way) that gives me this graph known as `f` and `x1`.

Comment: Is this the continuation of your question `Translation plot of some functions`? There was proposed an option for automation. What does not suit you?

Comment: `Piecewise[{{f[2], 2 - x1 <= x <= 2 + x1}, {f[x + x1], f'[x + x1] < 0}, {f[x - x1], f'[x - x1] > 0}}]`?

Answer (score 1):

Just to remove from "Unanswered". All credit goes to @jkuczm

```
Piecewise[{{f[2], 2 - x1 <= x <= 2 + x1}, {f[x + x1], f'[x + x1] < 0}, {f[x - x1], f'[x - x1] > 0}}]
```